# "Jest encountered an unexpected token" when trying to build Angular 10 Component Unit Test with FullCallendarModule

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to create a unit test for a component that uses FullCalendar for Angular. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
Details:
...........\node_modules\@fullcalendar\core\main.js:6
    import './vdom';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
    > 2 | import {FullCalendarModule}               from "@fullcalendar/angular";
        | ^
      3 | import dayGridPlugin                      from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
      4 | import interactionPlugin                  from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
      5 | import {CalendarComponent}                from "../../calendar/calendar.component";

      at Runtime._execModule (../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1179:56)
      at ../node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/bundles/fullcalendar-angular.umd.js:2:139
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/bundles/fullcalendar-angular.umd.js:5:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/private-pages/booking/booking-page.component.spec.ts:2:1)
```

Hope this is enough information for those who solved that problem in the past.  Please let me know if you need more information (eg. complete codes, etc.)

I found this SO answer which did not help in my case (propably it targets React but not Angular):
[customize-cra to compile node_modules for JEST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63728113/558239)

Comment: Presumably you're trying to use code this outside a module, which isn't allowed. That's a generic JS error, nothing specific to Jest, fullCalendar or Angular. The other answer you linked to seems to be for a different error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your testing file you need to mock full Calendar as follows:

`jest.mock('@fullcalendar/angular', () => () => <div />);`